# Remove parent parenthesis with regex

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Hoping for some assistance with what I assume to be a simple regex problem. I want to remove the parent set of parenthesis from a string, but preserve the child. For example:

```
gsub(some regex ,"LOG((X))")
```

would return

```
(X)
```

I've gotten close with

```
 gsub("LOG\\(|\\)","","LOG((X))")
```

But this returns

```
 (X
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: escaping both first and second parens, `gsub('LOG\\(\\(|\\)\\)',` with your `|` will get you there.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately this does not return (X), but it returns X

Comment: Can't you just match the inner parentheses with [`\([^()]+\)`](https://regex101.com/r/7H99Hh/1)? Either way, this question is a bit too vague. What does your input *looks like*? What can `X` in `LOG((X))` be? Can there be unmatched parentheses? Please edit your question so as to include enough details.

Comment: I misinterpreted your desired output, though on third reading it is clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a bit too robust, but if you want a vector with all levels of nesting, you can do something like this:

```
v <- c("LOG(EXP(X))", "A", "EXP(LOG(2*SIN(X)))")


unnest_parentheses <- function(x) {
  
  lapply(x, \(x) {
    
    start <- gregexpr("\\(", x)[[1]]
    end <- rev(gregexpr("\\)", x)[[1]])
    
    if (length(start) != length(end)) {
      
      stop("We either miss a starting or ending parentheses")
      
    } else {
      
      tree <- unlist(Map(f = \(start, end) {
        str_sub(x, start+1, end-1)
      }, start, end))
      tree <- c(x, tree) # comment out if you not want the parent
      tree[tree != ""]
      
    }
    
  })
  
}

unnest_parentheses(v)
```

**output**

```
[[1]]
[1] "LOG(EXP(X))" "EXP(X)"      "X"          

[[2]]
[1] "A"

[[3]]
[1] "EXP(LOG(2*SIN(X)))" "LOG(2*SIN(X))"      "2*SIN(X)"           "X"
```

Comment: Super useful answer! Solves my problem and the next one that I am likely to get, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will work. It should remove all but one closing parenthesis and all but one opening parenthesis. It does it in stages, so it assumes that the left side has only opening and the right only closing. It also isn't smart enough to keep proper nesting levels so it will kill all parenthesis on the right side of a nested equation; that's a more difficult question.

```r
remParen <- function(x) {
  gsub("\\(\\(+", "\\(",  gsub("\\)\\)+", "\\)", x))
}
```

Examples:

```r
A <- "LOG(((X)))"                    # Should Work
B <- "EXP((Y)))))"                   # Should Work
C <- "TAN(((EXP(((SQRT(((X)))))))))" # Wont work properly
D <- "()))((()())()X()()()()()"      # Wont work at all

> remParen(A)
[1] "LOG(X)"
> remParen(B)
[1] "EXP(Y)"
> remParen(C)
[1] "TAN(EXP(SQRT(X)"
> remParen(D)
[1] "()()()()X()()()()()"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe all I needed was the humble $ on the end of the regex

```
gsub("LOG\\(|\\)$","","LOG((X))")
```

Returns

```
(X)
```